# not able to install grub2 from live usb

Tags: grub2

When i try to install grub 2 by the command

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/grub2 /dev/sda
```

I get the error: `failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.`

When I try to install grub  by

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

message is:  `installation finished.no error reported`.

Then when I run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

I get the same error: `failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.`

I will give you brief why I was trying this.

I had old desktop with XP and Ubuntu 10.10.

I opened the system after 3 years. Everything was working. I thought to upgrade 10.10 to 14.04. made the bootable usb through 10.10.
Now installation is crashing at the stage of file transfer.
I have P4 system .. Hard disk is Sata( through convertor).
My cd drive is old & only cd WR... Have external dvd drive but  not booting the bootable dvd through usb.
Now I am trying to install the Ubuntu 14.04 through Hard disk.

To do same I need to install grub 2..

I do not know much of Linux and coding... all this i have understood by Google.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to mount /mnt and /boot before:

After booting the live USB, mount the Ubuntu partition to /mnt with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

Replace X with your disk partition number

If you have a separate /boot partition, we'll need to mount it in /mnt/boot as well:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaY /mnt/boot
```

Replace XYwith your /boot partition number

Now update grub with the correct root and target:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Comment: after running 1 st command i got the reply as

Comment: /dev/sda10 already mounted or   / mnt  busy

Comment: unmount it then mount as shown above `umount /dev/sdaX`