# Will not proceed with blocklists

Tags: boot, grub2

Every boot gives that error and it gets stuck just like here [Showing "Press 'Ctrl'+'C'" to cancel filesystem checks in progress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317688/showing-press-ctrlc-to-cancel-filesystem-checks-in-progress)

. So that is why i created usb live and chose "try ubuntu" option.

I have this error
Fix "press Ctrl-c to cancel the checks in progress on the filesystem" error from USB live stick

I followed here
[Ubuntu 20.04, every boot makes a very long filesystem check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237389/ubuntu-20-04-every-boot-makes-a-very-long-filesystem-check)

and lots of others but in try ubuntu session ,i could not edit fstab.

I did fsck but it did not give any errors.

I suspect huge log sizes but also despite i mounted hdd, i could not see any full size parts.

What i did is:

```
Add fsck.mode=skip to the linux line in grub.cfg just before quiet splash

It is recommended to add the command to grub.cfg by editing /etc/default/grub thus: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash" and then run sudo update-grub.
```

I used this to change laptop's grub:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and updated grub but it gave this error:

[Question about mounting, 'input not supported' error and grub-probe error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687138/question-about-mounting-input-not-supported-error-and-grub-probe-error-faile?noredirect=1&lq=1)

then i followed here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/633815/542988

but it gave that error:

[grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161746/grub-install-error-will-not-proceed-with-blocklists)

now i am stuck

WHen i do fdisk, it shows not sda. it shows like this:

[Filesystem shows /dev/nvme0n1p1 instead of /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932331/filesystem-shows-dev-nvme0n1p1-instead-of-dev-sda)

```
Device         Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 2048    718847    716800   350M  7 EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2       718848 245762047 245043200 116,9G  Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 245762048 878535144 632773097 301,7G  7 Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 878536702 976771071  98234370  46,9G  5 Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 878536704 960231423  81694720    39G 83 Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 960233472 976771071  16537600   7,9G 82 Linux filesystem
```

when i do lsblk it shows

```
nvme0n1 238 gb disk
-nvme0n1p1 976 mb
-nvme0n1p2 977mb
-nvme0n1p3 17 gb
-nvme0n1p4 5 gb
-nvme0n1p5 62 gb
-nvme0n1p6 151 gb
```

So nvme0n1  is my disk so imounted it.  also nvme0n1p1  is EFI, i also mounted it but still i got error:

```
rub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
```

grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists

I dont know what to do. I hope i did not lose any data.

How can i be sure that fsck loop is not about huge size of logs?

My pc is laptop and brand HP 15S-FQ2045NT . There is only ubuntu 20.04.

I also did fsck for  partitions. There were no errors. It was like this:

```
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
(0.2% non-contiguous), 7452718/155270656 blocks
```

commands:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2
sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p4
 sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5
sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p6
```

[ls -al](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63CSu.jpg) when i do

```
ls -al /boot
```

in recovery after pressing esc to go to that menu

WHen i click Recovery mode 5.8.0.55, it opened the menu of recovery mode. `resume clean dpkg fsck grub network root ystem summary.` i also chose root and edited boot cfg withk `skip fsck` then clicked update grub then rebooted but did not effect anything. It stucsk at logo.

Comment: What kind of computer are you using? Could you update your question with the brand and model? That might make it easier for someone to offer a specific solution 

Comment: I wrote how i fixed but i chose your answer to appreciate your efforst for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First... **STOP** what you're doing to fix this problem... as you may do more damage to your system. You don't appear to have the proper procedures.

Second... file system checks occur 1) when booting to a Ubuntu Live USB, and 2) when you boot to your normal system, and there's a file system problem.

Third... after rebooting normally, remove `fsck.mode=skip` from /etc/default/grub, and then `sudo update-grub`, after doing the following manual `fsck` steps...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p4`
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5`
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p6`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Try `boot-repair` to fix this problem. Use your Ubuntu Live USB. Get instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128103/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-will-not-proceed-with-blocklists) which is hopefully more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`/var` had %100 used space. I deleted journal files in recovery mode as root following [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1294072/542988).

It became %95 and I was able to log in. I need to fix whatever is causing `/var` to have low space also but this login problem is fixed now. Thank you heynnema